# ffmpeg does not accept variable name read from file

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I am attempting to batch download a number of videos using ffmpeg.  A list of the site addresses and save names is stored in a text file in the following format.

```
"site",filename.mp4
```

The code that I have is looping through the file and attempting to download each line by line.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read dl nm
do
    echo $dl
    echo $nm
    /usr/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel error -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto -i  $dl -c copy $nm
done < $1
```

The expected output is that on each loop ffmpeg would download the file indicated by each line and then proceed to the next iteration of the loop.

Instead, ffmpeg outputs the error message

```
"site": No such file or directory
```

When I run the same command directly in the terminal with the site name and save name directly inserted into the command, it works without any issue.

Looking at other posts seemingly related to this I have tried appending

```
< /dev/null
```

to the end of the ffmpeg call but it still has the same affect.

Comment: This looks like an issue with your script.  Which is the "input file" designator, the first or second option in the lines of text?  If it's the first option, then are you sure that "site" is actually a file location that ffmpeg can access?  Also, is there a reason you have thte "site" thing in quotes in the file itself?  It'll read all that literally, so the `$dl` variable will be equal to `"site"` which is probably *not* what you're after.

Comment: The input file is the first option.  And as I mentioned, using the input file directly in the terminal with quotes does work.  I just tested it with the modification `"$dl"` and removed the quote from the text file, which seems to be what you were referencing, and it appears to be working.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  I summarized the findings and the proper solution that you tested in an answer, so you can mark the question as answered and accept the answer (if you wish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some issues with your script, in that you're using quotes in the file with download URLs/locations.

Namely, that when you have the file the way you do, `$dl` becomes `"site" and`$nm` remains as you'd expect.

In order to do this, you either need to change the file so that the site download locations don't have quotes, and then you need to set quotes around `$dl` in the script.

So you'd end up with this:

*input file list:*

```
site,foobar.baz
```

*Script:*

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read dl nm
do
    echo $dl
    echo $nm
    /usr/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel error -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto -i "$dl" -c copy $nm
done < $1
```

You might also want to wrap `$nm` in quotes as well in case you have a filename that has spaces in it, but that's your decision or not.